# Array multi sorting 2 keys error

Tags: php, sorting, numbers, key

i stuck here about some Php codes. I hope you can help me. 
I'm just new at sorting array values. So..

I wrote some codes about student averages by classes. But here when i sad to sort by desc to value `arsort()` he is just sorts keys by desc. 
how can i resolve this?

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [354] => 0
            [325] => 0
            [312] => 0
            [313] => 0
            [314] => 0
            [307] => 0
            [308] => 0
            [309] => 0
            [316] => 0
            [317] => 0
            [323] => 0
            [350] => 0
            [347] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [16] => 84.444444444447
            [7] => 57.777777777778
            [13] => 41.666666666667
            [12] => 31.111111111111
            [8] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [43] => 88.333333333335
            [41] => 81.666666666665
            [51] => 79.25925925926
            [44] => 76
            [53] => 73.333333333335
            [42] => 72
            [52] => 62.777777777777
            [54] => 51.851851851853
            [38] => 45
            [35] => 0
            [50] => 0
        )

)
```

He is just sorting the keys. But i sad arsort() about the values. Anyway, how can do it with my values.

i want to sort values by desc.

Comment: What does google say for "sorting array by values php" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sort this `[354] => 0
            [325] => 0
            [312] => 0
            [313] => 0` keys then use this function

```
function arraySort($array){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    krsort($value);
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: yes. i did it with arsort for the value sorting. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try asort() instead of arsort().

See: http://php.net/asort#refsect1-function.asort-examples